# Capture an image in Android and send it via MMS

Tags: android

We are developing an app that will need to capture camera image and send it via MMS. (large or small image please)

Based on a method invocation in another activity, take an image and send it via MMS

This is one of the last two parts left for us.

Thanks a milion.

Mat

Answer (score 2):

Your statement says **you** are developing the application, not **us**.

Have you done anything?  What approaches have you tried that led you to come here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an intent, a quick example of sending an MMS via an intent can be found [here](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/101/).

Comment: Another example:

http://snipplr.com/view/13771/send-image-via-gmail-or-mms-on-android/